# How does a rails app know where to pull an ENV variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, environment-variables

I am curious exactly how ENV[SOME_VARIABLE] tries to find the data with a standard rails install in a mac environment.

I encountered a problem that I overcame using the figaro gem, but it didn't answer my questions as to why it didn't work. I am no longer interested in troubleshooting the problem, but am interested in learning the specifics of how ENV[SOME_VARIABLE] finds that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you run a command on your computer, some other program is running that command. That parent program can provide settings to that child; these are generally known as *environment variables*.

If you open a terminal window on your Mac, you're looking at a *shell*. This is a command-line interface to your computer. It's running inside the terminal program, which itself is running inside something else - either your dock, or from Spotlight, or from the Finder (depending on how you ran it). By extension, if you run your Rails program by running `rails server`, the `rails` command is being run by your shell.

There's a number of ways to set environment variables in the shell. If you run `export` in a terminal, you should see a whole bunch. Your shell will set some automatically for you; common ones include `HOME` for your home directory, `PATH` for the locations to look for executable files, and `USER` for your username. You can print out these values by prepending a `$` sign. You can also set your own by using the `export` command.

```
bob@host ~$ echo $USER
bob
bob@host ~$ echo $HOME
/Users/bob
bob@host ~$ export MYVAR="whatever"
bob@host ~$ echo $MYVAR
whatever
```

Anything you set using `export` will only exist until you close that terminal, and won't carry over into new terminals. You can put your `export` commands in a file that gets run when you open your terminal; [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) is the default shell on Macs, so you can edit your `~/.bashrc` file to make it available in all terminals.

---

So let's go back to your `rails server` command. Let's say you wanted to provide a `SECRET_KEY` environment variable so you don't have to entrust that secret to your source control. You could put it in your `.bashrc`, as seen above. You could also provide it when you run your server, by setting it before the command:

```
bob@host rails_app$ SECRET_KEY=abc1234 rails server
```

You can also use add-ons like [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) and [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) to manage your settings in files. Inside Ruby, `ENV` is just a hash - a special hash provided to you by Ruby itself, but just a hash. Any code can add keys, delete keys, or change values within it. I haven't looked at the code for dotenv or Figaro, but I bet that's what they're doing - they're loading themselves via an [initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files), reading the files where the environment variables are configured, and adding these environment variables to `ENV`.

Answer (score 0):

**Environment Variables**

To simplify `Alex P`'s answer, [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) are defined in the operating system - meaning they are available to any application which wishes to use them:

> Environment variables are a set of dynamic named values that can
>   affect the way running processes will behave on a computer.

Rails uses `environment variables` for a number of reasons, but mainly for security. If your application uses the likes of `API` keys etc, the `environment variables` allow you to define the sensitive information in a way which is *only* accessible at OS-level

This means if you run your Rails application on a host which is hacked, and your code is compromised, the hackers will not have full access to your data, as the ENV vars are stored in the OS.

*How* this works is described in `Alex`'s answer

--

[**Rails "Secrets" YML**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config/secrets.yml)

One of the advances with Rails 4.1+ is the introduction of the `secrets` gem. This is designed to give you the same functionality as the `ENV` vars, except you'll be able to keep all your values local to your Rails app:

> Rails 4.1 generates a new secrets.yml file in the config folder. By
>   default, this file contains the application's secret_key_base, but it
>   could also be used to store other secrets such as access keys for
>   external APIs.
>
> The secrets added to this file are accessible via
>   Rails.application.secrets. For example, with the following
>   config/secrets.yml

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 3b7cd727ee24e8444053437c36cc66c3
  some_api_key: SOMEKEY
```